# Is it poor form to post multiple possibilities in an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Let's say there is a riddle, and I am unsure of the answer but have narrowed it down to, say, 2 possibilities.

Would it be in poor form to post a single answer that says "Either it's A, or it's B"?

What about posting multiple answers, one for A and one for B? That doesn't seem acceptable to me but might as well ask since I'm on the topic.

I don't spend a lot of time here and don't really know what the culture is like.

Comment: I would say the proper way is to post multiple answers if the possibilities are unrelated to each other, but keep them in a single answer if the possibilities are similar. However, I think it's more common to always put them in one answer.

Comment: I think that what earns votes is the reasoning you used to arrive at your answer. I agree with others in that completely different interpretations of a riddle, leading to different answers, deserve separate Answers. But for example a single line of reasoning leading to "It's some kind of bird but I don't know which" deserves one Answer. Similarly for mathematical puzzles where a single line of reasoning leads to "8 or 9 but I don't know which".

Answer (score 4):

Multiple answers would be fine as long as they both fit all of the clues. (The riddle would probably be closed shortly after the answers were posted, though - too many answers means a puzzle is too broad.)

It'd also be fine to post both in the same answer. I'd generally lean toward this if they were related (like, if "pen" and "pencil" were both potential answers to a riddle), and toward separate answers if they were entirely different.

Comment: Personally, I feel that there should never be separate solutions in a single post.  There's nothing wrong with multiple posts.  Also, if you post a solution, and later on come up with a different idea, *don't* edit your previous post to add or change to the new solution.  Just post again.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: Yeah, edits shouldn't vastly change the original. I only recommend same-post solutions if they're very similar - similar enough such that the clues fit in the same way.

Comment: Sorry, I got on a bit of a soapbox there.  Wasn't ranting against you, just the internet in general.

Comment: +1 for (too many answers means a puzzle is too broad).